# delete all folders containing deployfiles but not containing name DEV in absolute path

Tags: find, solaris, posix, ansible

I would like a generic/posix/ansible solution to the below requirement for  non-windows(preferably Solaris and Linux)

-> I wish to list all files under `/web/bea_apps/dev/TomcatNode01/deploy`
-> Then delete all `deployfiles` folders which meet the below criteria:

Condition 1: The file path of the found files should contain `deployfiles`

Condition 2: The file path should not contain case-insensitive `dev`(which will come from a variable)

Below Attempts did not help:

Note: In my attempt I have hard code the environment `DEV` but it will be an ansible or shell script variable.

```
find /web/bea_apps/dev/TomcatNode01/deploy \( -type d -name '*deployfiles*' -a ! -type d -name '*DEV*' \) -print
find /web/bea_apps/dev/TomcatNode01/deploy -type d -iname '*deployfiles*' ! -iname '*DEV*' -print
find /web/bea_apps/dev/TomcatNode01/deploy \( -type d -name '*deployfiles*' -o ! -type d -name '*DEV*' \) -print
```

Output:

```
/web/bea_apps/dev/TomcatNode01/deploy/conf/src/config/qa/deployfiles

/web/bea_apps/dev/TomcatNode01/deploy/conf/src/config/dev/deployfiles

/web/bea_apps/dev/TomcatNode01/deploy/conf/src/config/uat/deployfiles

/web/bea_apps/dev/TomcatNode01/deploy/conf/src/config/prod/deployfiles

/web/bea_apps/dev/TomcatNode01/deploy/conf/src/config/perf/deployfiles
```

Expected output:

```
/web/bea_apps/dev/TomcatNode01/deploy/conf/src/config/qa/deployfiles
  
/web/bea_apps/dev/TomcatNode01/deploy/conf/src/config/uat/deployfiles

/web/bea_apps/dev/TomcatNode01/deploy/conf/src/config/prod/deployfiles

/web/bea_apps/dev/TomcatNode01/deploy/conf/src/config/perf/deployfiles
```

Thus; if `QA` is passed the below would be the expected output:

```
/web/bea_apps/dev/TomcatNode01/deploy/conf/src/config/dev/deployfiles

/web/bea_apps/dev/TomcatNode01/deploy/conf/src/config/uat/deployfiles

/web/bea_apps/dev/TomcatNode01/deploy/conf/src/config/prod/deployfiles

/web/bea_apps/dev/TomcatNode01/deploy/conf/src/config/perf/deployfiles
```

OS version:

```
uname -a

SunOS usdfw33as77v 5.11 11.4.62.151.3 sun4v sparc sun4v non-global-zone
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Would you please articulate your question in your original post? I don't know what your question is.

Comment: @paladin i updated my original post.

Comment: Please re articulate your entire post. I really don't get what you want. Your first sentence is "I would like the same solution to run on all non-windows preferably Solaris and Linux.". What solution do you mean? Your headline is insufficient and doesn't explain your problem, the headline is even irritating.

Comment: @paladin done. Hope its better now?

Comment: @Ashar What exact version(s) of Solaris?  The exact version(s) are important because later versions of Solaris will likely have more GNU-based tools available, which makes the use of the non-standard extensions that are widespread in GNU tools potentially available for your use.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `uname -a

SunOS remotehost 5.11 11.4.62.151.3 sun4v sparc sun4v non-global-zone`

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Using GNU-extensions would counteract the stated goal of "I would like a generic/posix/ansible solution", no? Using any GNU-extension would make it non-POSIX.

Comment: @bakunin True, but "generic" was also specified, and "generic" needs to be defined, as does the practical meaning of "generic/posix/ansible".

Comment: @AndrewHenle: also true. My suggestion (to thread-O/P) is to better state/clarify what his goals are: generic? (if yes: generic to what environment?), POSIX?, Ansible? (although I don't know of Ansible as an environment in itself).